# Solve the following recurrence

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, data-structures, recursion, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve this the recurrence :
$$
T(n)=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } n = 1 \\ 
T(n-1) +n(n-1), & \text{ if } n \geq 2
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: $1 + \dfrac{(n-1)n(n+1)}3$, if you want a closed formula.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T(n)=T(n-1)$, using induction we can prove that $T(n)= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1) \le 2\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)$

Now, calculating $\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)$ gives us:

$\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)=\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2 - k) = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 - \sum_{k=1}^n k$

Using [this formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/sum-of-first-n-squares-equals-fracnn12n16), we know that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$, and its not hard to show that $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n (n+1)}{2}$

Therefore, $T(n) \le 2\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - \frac{n (n+1)}{2}\right) = O(n^3)$

Comment: A lower bound can be given using the same proof, replace the $\le$ with $\ge$ and replace the multiplication by $2$ with multiplication by $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I don't understand the second step. Can you explain that line?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you didn't understand? What equation in the line don't you understand?

Comment: The line that you using induction to prove $$
T(n)=1+∑nk=1k(k−1)≤2∑nk=1k(k−1)
$$

Comment: $T(n)=T(n-1)+n(n-1)=T(n-2)+(n-1)(n-2)+n(n-1)=T(n-3)+(n-2)(n-3)+(n-1)(n-2)+n(n-1)=...=T(1) + \sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)$

Comment: Basically, use the definition of $T$ multiple times. Each time you use it, it will add a factor $k(k-1)$ to the summation.